# How obtain a CDF from a PDF?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

A) I calculate first the pdf. I'm not sure if it is correct.{I corrected the rages}

[image]

and from there I integrate the intervals given. My problem is that when I integrate the final cdf is not 1, clearly something wrong I'm doing.

C) I will use the pdf. 
   (i) I integrate between - infitiny to +infinity.

***I need help with this step, I can not find the cdf that all the summ is

        equal to 1.**
    [I break down all the interval and all the sum still gave me -5/2]

(c) Calculate P(X<3|X>2);
    (i) I integrate between -inifinity and 3.
    (ii) I integrate between 2 and infinity.
    and I obtain my finaly answer from I dividided (ii)/(i)
    **Is that correct??**

d) To find E(X) I will intagreate  x*pfd in all the intervalls.

In conclusion, I want to know how to obtaing correctly cdf, and if my steps are correct. Thanks.

Comment: The PDF is incorrect. Start with $[1,2]$, what is $f(2)$ already?

Comment: Your $f(x)$ has value ?how much? when $x = 2.5$? Is this reasonable?

Comment: I corrected again. But I'm not sure yet. Thanks to be there :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A) Your PDF has a mistake: second line should be

$$ x/2 - 1/2\qquad\text{if $1\leq x\lt 2$}.$$

The CDF can then be found as follows:

$$F(x) = \begin{cases}
x\leq 1 &: \quad 0 \\
& \\
1\lt x\leq 2 &: \quad F(1) + \int_1^x(u/2-1/2)du = 0+\left[u^2/4-u/2\right]_1^x \\
& \quad = x^2/4-x/2-1/4 \\
& \\
2\lt x\leq 3 &: \quad F(2) + \int_2^x(-u/2+3/2)du = 1/4+\left[-u^2/4+3u/2\right]_2^x \\
& \quad = -x^2/4+3x/2-7/4 \\
& \\
3\lt x\leq 4 &: \quad F(3) = 1/2 \\
& \\
4\lt x\leq 4.5 &: \quad F(4) + \int_4^x 1du = 1/2+\left[u\right]_4^x \\
& \quad = x-7/2 \\
& \\
4.5\lt x &: \quad F(4.5) = 1.
\end{cases}$$

(C) That's not quite right. The basic rule of conditional probability is, for events $A,B,\;$ that $P(A\mid B) = P(A\cap B)/P(B)$. Therefore,

\begin{align}
P(X\lt 3\mid X\gt 2) &= \dfrac{P(2\lt X\lt 3)}{P(X\gt 2) } \\
&= \dfrac{F(3)-F(2)}{1-F(2)} \\
&= \dfrac{1/2-1/4}{1-1/4} = \dfrac{1}{3}.
\end{align}

(D) Your method for $E(X)$ looks correct.